# How to view definition of security policies on Azure Synapse db

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-synapse

is there any possibility to query the definition behind an Azure Synapse Analytics security policy that has been applied on a table?

I can see the list of security policies from sys.security_policies but when I try to the following code to view the definition behind, it does not return anything:

```sql
SELECT sm.object_id,   
   OBJECT_NAME(sm.object_id) AS object_name,   
   o.type,   
   o.type_desc,   
   sm.definition,  
   sm.uses_ansi_nulls,  
   sm.uses_quoted_identifier,  
   sm.is_schema_bound,  
   sm.execute_as_principal_id  
-- using the two system tables sys.sql_modules and sys.objects  
FROM sys.all_sql_modules AS sm  
JOIN sys.objects AS o ON sm.object_id = o.object_id    
WHERE sm.object_id = OBJECT_ID('my_schema.my_policy_name')  
ORDER BY o.type;
```

Is there any way to query definitions of security policies?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve by mentioning `definition of security policies`. There is no such requirement or feature request available in Microsoft official documents and any third-party article/forum.

The maximum you can try is to query `sys.security_policies` which returns a row for each security policy in the database. Refer [sys.security_policies (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-security-policies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for more details. Apart from this **there is no support in Azure Synapse to query definitions of security policies.**